# C# MVC: View with optional ViewModel (data not always present / necessary)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm kind of stuck on an MVC problem.

I have a registration view, reached by www.example.com/register, something like this:

```
<form id="registrationform" method="post">
<fieldset>
    <label for="emailaddress">Email</label>
    <input id="emailaddress" name="emailaddress" type="text" />
    //more inputs etc. 
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Now I allow people to invite others, so I'm checking in my controller's Register method for an invite parameter (www.example.com/register?invite=1234). If the invite parameter is not empty, I do a lookup in my database to get the associated "invited" user. That all works fine.

Now the problem: I want to prepopulate my inputs with the data from the database. I already have the data, I just don't know about the best way to put it into the MVC view, and disable the inputs that are now already populated.

ViewModel? Keep in mind that I need the view regularly empty (I don't want to use different views, that would violate DRY).

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your View Model:

```
public class RegistrationViewModel
{
    public bool Invited;

    /*
     * Fields for prepopulating inputs
     */
}
```

In your View:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("email", null, Model.Invited ? new { @readonly = "readonly"} : null) %>
```

or

```
<%= Html.TextBox("email", null, Model.Invited ? new { @disabled = "disabled"} : null) %>
```

Comment: Is there any performance impact on using Html.Textbox instead of directly writing <input ... etc. ?

Comment: Absolutely NO. Use Html.Textbox where it is possible

Comment: What are the advantages of Html.* over the direct tag equivalent? Just trying to understand the reasoning. Thank you :)

Comment: Html.Textbox("value" ...) populates its value from ViewData or ModelState (if there is no "value" in the ViewData). Also it is possible to define "default" value (if both ViewData and ModelState are empty). It also minimizes the possibility of rendering incorrect markup.

Comment: How could I have my POST /register return the ViewModel? (e.g. Register(RegistrationViewModel registrationVM) then? So I don't have to use FormCollection...

Comment: On POST you must use Model, not View Model (Register(UserModel user)). You Model will be populated by DefaultModelBinder or your custom ModelBinder.

Comment: A couple of articles, you may be interested:
 (1) http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/02/27/chapter-5-understanding-models.aspx
 (2) http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/04/13/asp.net-mvc-tip-50-ndash-create-view-models.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that you create a ViewModel and have your View be totally unaware of the fact that data is or is not coming prepopulated from the DB at all.

If you are prepopulating data.. then fill your ViewModel with the necessary data (and disable the inputs that are coming prepopulated)

If you are starting from scratch.. then fill your ViewModel with empty/default data

Either way, all your view does is display the form, and populate default data on the various textboxes and other inputs based upon the passed in ViewModel.